# SQL Server query to get uniques rows only but only once from table

Tags: sql-server

I have this SQL Server table :

[image]

I want to write a query to get all the information in Dataset for all the categories. But I need on category once starting from below. So the result should be Like

```
Row 9, Row 7, Row 6, Row 3, Row 2
```

With rows with same `ItemCategoryID` repeating once. Kindly let me know as I am not so good in creating queries.

Comment: there are two records for itemcategoryID = 2, what do you want to show then? both or only one?

Comment: @JW웃 I want to show only one which ever has greater MinPriceID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  MinPriceID, BasePrice, MinPrice, MinPriceDate, ItemCategoryID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemCategoryID ORDER BY MinPriceID DESC) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
SELECT  MinPriceID, BasePrice, MinPrice, MinPriceDate, ItemCategoryID
FROM    records
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: here [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is a thypical way of doing it...

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `itemcategoryID` DESC
```

Comment: I do know that ! By like i said i need them once not all the records!